# Complicated querying databases

Tags: django, django-models

Please see scenario below:

```
class Case(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    documentation = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)


class Suite(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    documentation = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    cases = models.ManyToManyField(Case, through='SuiteThroughModel')



class Project(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    documentation = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    suites = models.ManyToManyField(Suite, through='ProjectSuiteThroughModel')


class ProjectSuiteThroughModel(OrderedModel):

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    suite = models.ForeignKey(Suite, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class SuiteThroughModel(OrderedModel):

    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    suite = models.ForeignKey(Suite, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I'm trying to do is to retrieve all suites from a particular Project.
This is how I went about it:

```
project = Project.objects.get(name='xyz')
suites = project.suites.all() # outputs nothing
```

In Django docs I learned that I can get the data from the other end of the query:

```
suites = Suite.objects.filter(project__name='xyz') # outputs nothing
suites = Suite.objects.filter(projectsuitethroughmodel__project__name='xyz') # outputs nothing
```

The data is there but how can I access it ?

Comment: Are you sure the data is there? So there is a `SuiteThroughModel` that links the `project` (with name `'xyz'`) to one or more `Suite`s? I'm not convinced that the data here is (correctly) linked.

Comment: Yes the data is there because when I run `Suite.objects.all()` or `Case.objects.all()` it comes up.

Comment: but you did *link* the `Suite`s and `Case`s to *that* `Project`?

Comment: Through this `suites = models.ManyToManyField(Suite, through='ProjectSuiteThroughModel')` I should be able to access `Suite`s and `Case`s.

Comment: Mark: yes, but then you retrieve the *related* `Suite`s and `Case`s, so the `Suite`s that *belong* to the (here) `Project`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem . I'm not sure if I understand. I see the relationships defined in models, that means every single instance of Project is linked to its `Suite`s and `Case`s.

Comment: You have to explicitly link a Project and a Suite somewhere.

Comment: @luxcem . So defining relationship field isn't enough ?

Comment: @luxcem: defining a relation means that you say that you *can* link zero, one or many `Project`s to zero, one or many `Case`s. That does not mean that these *are* linked.

Comment: This is the first time I'm reading this. Can you give me an example ?

Comment: Check the ManyToMany entry in the django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the link. I understand I need to use:
`suite.cases.add(case)
           project.suites.add(suite)` . But then it complains about `NOT NULL constraint failed for SuiteThroughModel`. Adding `blank=True` didn't do the trick. How do I deal with it ? Does it mean that I need to link the `ForeignKey`s as well ?

Answer (score -1):

As @WillemVanOnsem and @luxcem pointed out. I needed to link the tables explicitly.